Can my employer track files if I copy files saved in my computer to my local network storage?
Can my employer track files if I copy files saved in my computer to my local network storage.
I'm working at home so I'm using my own local WiFi. I also don't think my computer has VPN on my computer.

Your employers can install any tracking software that they like,
which can keep a history of what you do, even with screenshots,
and transmit whenever asked.
Although such spying is a bit extreme and unlikely to be so in your
case, such software does exist, and there are stories about such cases.
If these are your private files, I suggest asking for permission.
If these are company files, I suggest to avoid doing that.

If it's a computer that belongs to a domain (AD, LDAP etc) I would not copy any files anywhere if it isn't explicitly allowed by your company. Also, as @harrymc pointed out, there can be a software installed on your PC. It's called DLP (Data Leak Prevention) and it can be pretty complex to try to tackle with it.
The short answer: yes, your employer can track files that you copy. It depends on several factors which you rather cannot predict (at least without full admin's privileges).
